# Variadic templates. Some issues

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template <class... T_values>
class Thing {
public:
  void something(T_values... values) {
    tuple_ = std::tuple<T_values...>(values...);
  }

  void do_something_with_values() {
     call_yadda_with_tuple(tuple_,
      std::index_sequence_for<T_value...>())
  }

  void yadda(T... values);

private:
  //The helper method.
  template<std::size_t... Is>
  void call_yadda_with_tuple(const std::tuple<T_values...>& tuple,
    std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    yadda(std::get<Is>(tuple)...);
  }

  std::tuple<T_values...> tuple_;
};
```

Above sourcecode comes from: https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2015/12/05/modern-c-variadic-template-parameters-and-tuples/

I would like to ask some questions:

1. What does return `std::index_sequence_for<T_value...>())` ?
2. Why in `yadda(std::get<Is>(tuple)...);` there is `Is` instead of `Is...`? Therefore, what does it mean `Is`? `Is...` in unpacked ( expanded ) types pack but what is `Is`.
3. Especially, which `std::get` fits from (1)-(8)
   (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get)
4. Why `call_yadda_with_tuple` gets `std::index_sequence<Is...>`.
   After all, this argument is nameless so it is useless. I suppose that it is connected with deduction types but I cannot see how does it help?

Comment: #2 `std::get<Is>(tuple)...` unpacks the entire expression for each value of `Is...`

Comment: #3 is of the form 1-4 (i.e. `get<0>(tuple)` will return the 1st entry in the tuple, `get<1>(tuple)` will return 2nd and so on...) The template argument is a numeric index which gives the tuple entry to return - NOTE: this is compile time..

Comment: #4 the argument to the function itself is redundant, the deduced type (which provides the index sequence is what is relevant here, in this case the sequence of numbers `0,1,2,3` etc.)

Comment: `std::index_sequence` is a `size_t` specialization of `std::integer_sequence`. It might help you to read the proposal for `integer_sequence` here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3658.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does return std::index_sequence_for()) ?

assuming T_value... is T, T, T (i.e. 3 types...)

```
std::index_sequence<0, 1, 2>
```

> Why in yadda(std::get(tuple)...); there is Is instead of Is...? Therefore, what does it mean Is? Is... in unpacked ( expanded ) types pack but what is Is.

`Is` represents 'the current value of Is' while `Is...` is being unpacked. The trailing `...` causes unpacking of the expression in which `Is` is used.

> Especially, which std::get fits from (1)-(8) (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get)

In this case the tuple reference is a `const std::tuple<T_values...>&` so it'll be number 3.

> Why call_yadda_with_tuple gets std::index_sequence. After all, this argument is nameless so it is useless. I suppose that it is connected with deduction types but I cannot see how does it help?

It's there simply to cause `Is...` to exist and therefore allow you to expand across all `Is` in the sequence.

edit:

Here's an example with comments that hopefully explain what's going on

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// for any value I, write a comma and space to stdout
// (i.e. ignore the value I)
template<std::size_t I>
void emit_sep()
{
    std::cout << ", ";
}

// specialise for when I is zero... no comma in this case
template<>
void emit_sep<0>()
{
}

// emit and value at some position I. Use emit_sep<I> to determine whether
// to print a separator
template<std::size_t I, class T>
void emit(const T& t)
{
    emit_sep<I>();
    std::cout << t;
}

// given a tuple type and a sequence of integers (Is...) emit the value
// at each index position of the tuple. Take care to emit a separator only
// before each element after the first one
template<class Tuple, size_t...Is>
void impl_show_it(const Tuple& tup, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using expand = int[];

    std::cout << "here are the indexes in the index_sequence: ";
    // the following line will expand (in our example) to:
    // void(int[] { 0, 
    //      (emit<0>(0), 0),
    //      (emit<1>(1), 0),
    //      (emit<2>(2), 0),
    //      });
    // and the optimiser will remove the operations which have no observable
    // side-effects (namely, building an array of ints which is never used)
    // so the code emitted will be equivalent to:
    // emit<0>(0); emit<1>(1); emit<2>(2);
    //
    void(expand {
        0,
        (emit<Is>(Is), 0)...
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "here are the values in the tuple: ";
    void(expand {
        0,
        (emit<Is>(std::get<Is>(tup)), 0)...
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// for some tuple type, compute the size of the tuple, build an index sequence
// representing each INDEX in the tuple and then use that sequence to call
// impl_show_it in order to actually perform the write
template<class Tuple>
void show_it(const Tuple& tup)
{
    constexpr auto tuple_size = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value;
    auto sequence = std::make_index_sequence<tuple_size>();
    impl_show_it(tup, sequence);
}

// make a tuple and then show it on stdout
int main()
{
    auto t = std::make_tuple(6, std::string("hello"), 5.5);
    show_it(t);
}
```

expected results:

```
here are the indexes in the index_sequence: 0, 1, 2
here are the values in the tuple: 6, hello, 5.5
```

Comment: #3 he's asking you to follow the link and tell him which of the 8 variants of std::get listed is the one being invoked

Comment: Is represents 'the current value of Is' while Is... is being unpacked. The trailing ... causes unpacking of the expression in which Is is used.

I still don't understand. Please explain more :)

Comment: @J.Doe added an example which you can compile (c++14). Hopefully the inline comments will get you started.